# Refresh Captcha Image on JQUERY Dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I've a **jquery model dialg** box below. When user clicks on one of the link on page, the dialog box appears with Captcha. When user enters the invalid captch the captch image *should be refreshed* and should show new text. But this is not happening. Below is the code snippet:

```
<div id="model">   
    <img id="captchaImage" src="@Url.Content("~/CaptchaImage.ashx?text=" + ViewBag.EncryptedCaptcha)" />  
    <input id="captchText" type="text" value="" />
    <a href="#"id="verfiyCaptcha">Validate</a>
</div>
```

When user clicks on Validate, the text is sent to MVC controller via **$.getJSON**. The controller returns back isCpatchValid and encryptedText  wrapped in JSON object Captcha. I've a done below if
 the captcha text is not valid:

> $("#captchaImage").attr("src", "~/CaptchaImage.ashx?text=" +
>   Captcha.encryptedText);

On Chrome debugger I can see the controller is returning a correct encrypted text. But this line above doesn't deem to fresh the captch image. I suspect this is due to async call.

COuld someone please help me with how to refresh the captcha image on Jauery Dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the "~" feature in javascript. That's a .NET thing. You'll need to wrap it around a .NET call, like:

```
attr("src", "@Url.Content("~/CaptchaImage.ashx")?text=" + Captcha.encryptedText)
```

Or if this JS is in a separate file, you can define a variable back on the view, then use it in the JS file, like:

```
** in the view **
var CAPTCHA_IMAGE_URL = "@Url.Content("~/CaptchaImage.ashx")";

** in the JS file **
attr("src", CAPTCHA_IMAGE_URL + "?text=" + Captcha.encryptedText)
```